# How can I push unclosed divs into my array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Wondering why this one throws an error:

```
arraysOfUserResults.push(<div>)
arraysOfUserResults.push("line of text")
arraysOfUserResults.push(</div>)
```

I'm writing this before the return method.

Basically what I'm trying to do is a loop like this: (*pseudo code*)

```
Start of object's keys iterating Loop
push opening of div with class name to the array
   Start of object values iterating loop
   push these values to the array
push closing of div to array
```

Then, place this array on the return method inside curly brackets.

Thank you.

Comment: Is that a typo ? div should be "div", and what's the error?

Comment: This appears to be an [X/Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve? What do you _need_ this for?

Comment: I'm trying to do this in three lines:
myArray.push(<div>line of text</div>)

Comment: You have quotes around `<div>` and `</div>` right? Like `arraysOfUserResults.push("<div>")` and `arraysOfUserResults.push("</div>")`? I only ask because in your question you're showing it without quotes.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie I don't, because that would return the string. I want to push JSX,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSX, `<div>line of text</div>` is just [syntactic sugar for `React.createElement('div', null, 'line of text')`](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html). So writing

```
arraysOfUserResults.push(
  <div>
)
arraysOfUserResults.push(
  "line of text"
)
arraysOfUserResults.push(
  </div>
)
```

is akin to writing

```
arraysOfUserResults.push(
  React.createElement('div', null,
)
arraysOfUserResults.push(
  "line of text"
)
arraysOfUserResults.push(
  )
)
```

which doesn't make any sense. Opening and closing tags only delimit the boundaries of an element. When your code runs, they don't exist.

If `"line of text"` is really supposed to be an array of values of an object, *and those values are primitives*, you can include them in the JSX as a JavaScript expression:

```
<div>{Object.values(myObject)}</div>
```

Each value will become a child of the `<div>`.